# C choose a specific function implementation (present in numerous libraries)

Tags: c, shared-libraries

My C program (on linux) uses two shared libraries that I have created.    Both of them use a function `getSample()` that is declared in an external (external to those libraries) header `GPSInterface.h`

Of course both libraries implement this function differently.

> My question is: How can I choose which implementation to use ?

I have tried to include them separately but didn't help.
as in:

```
//#include "lib1.h" /*COMMENTED OUT BUT STILL RUNS*/
#include "lib2.h" 
.
.
int status = getSample(); //lib1's implementation is ran no matter what!
```

The only way I could force the use of a specific implementation is by changing the order of the libraries in the project's options in the IDE, however, I assume there must be a more practical and correct way.

Comment: Including header files doesn't help you here, all a header file does is to declare the function, i.e. tell the compiler that a symbol with the name `getSample` exists somewhere and that it is a function returning an `int` and taking no arguments. That's it It's the *linking* phase that is run after the compiler that handles resolving symbols to actual functions. If you need both libraries, then try changing the order in which they are linked, otherwise remove one or the other.

Comment: Also, do note that trying to do something like this, use functions with the same name but from different libraries, is a really bad idea and will lead to maintenance problems. It needs to be documented extensively.

Comment: Yeah.. I think that is what I'll have to do - only have one of the libraries linked at any given time. Thanks .

Comment: You cannot without major pain. Just about the only way I can think of is loading the libraries dynamically (dlopen) and getting the funnction addresses with dlsym. It should be much easier to rename the functions to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically open the libraries with `dlopen`, then ask for the `getSample` symbol with `dlsym` and call the appropriate function version directly. This is a common pattern for .so files that act as plugins and which conform to a particular API (and so must have the same function names).

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

int getSamplesFrom(const char *lib) {
    void *lib = dlopen(lib, RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!lib) return -1;

    int sample = 0;
    int (*func)(void) = (int (*)(void)) dlsym(lib, "getSample");
    if(func) {
        sample = func();
    }

    dlclose(lib);
    return sample;
}
```

Of course you would declare the function pointer to have the right signature to suit your needs.